# Java generic method constraints - exclude type from constraint to prevent erasure problems?

Tags: java, generics, type-constraints

I am trying to overload a method based on type constraints. The code looks something like this:

```
protected  static <T extends ComponentTemplate> void addComponent(List<ComponentTemplate> factors, T component)
{
    ...
}

    protected  static <T extends ComponentTemplate
                       & ConditionalComponent> void addComponent(List<ComponentTemplate> factors, T conditionalComponent)
{
    ....
}
```

`ComponentTemplate` is an abstract class, and `ConditionalComponent` is an interface. These two methods can add a component to a list of components. In the case that the component implements `ConditionalComponent`, there will be additional methods that should be used to determine if the specific component should be added. A completely different approach is used when the object does not implement `ConditionalComponent`.

The problem is that these methods have the same erasure (according to RAD, which of course refuses to compile this). Is there a way to define the first method such that it *excludes* any objects that extends *both* `ComponentTemplate` AND `ConditionalComponent`? I imagined something like this:

```
    protected  static <T extends ComponentTemplate
                       & !ConditionalComponent> void addComponent(List<ComponentTemplate> factors, T component)
{
    ...
}
```

But of course, that doesn't work (it's not valid syntax). Is what I'm trying to do even possible, or is there a work-around?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: I think it's time for you to rethink on what distinct behaviors these methods are supposed to provide and come with different (more meaningful) signatures (specially the **names**) for both.

Comment: What would be the expected behaviour when `CT extends CC`. There would be no way of deciding which method to call.

Comment: @ggovan: ConditionalComponent is actually an interface, probably should have put that in the original question. When a CT object implements CC it will have implement some specific functionality. When a CT does *not* implement CC, it will not have those functions so the logic that is used to add the component will have to be different.

Comment: I think it's only logical to not allow this: if you know a shortcut to add a `ConditionalComponent` have the method check for the interface with `instanceof` (it's an internal property of your method). But as it stands, each object passed in is *also* a `ComponentTemplate` so should be handled by a single `addComponent` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not allowed. Why not?

When methods are called in Java, the method with the most specific type signiture is used.

In the example:

```
interface A {...}
interface B {...}
class X extends A, B {...}

void f(X);
void f(A);
void f(B);

X x = ...
f(x); // calls f(X)
f((A)x); // calls f(A)
f((B)x); // calls f(B)
```

We all know how to cast to call the correct method we want.

But in the example

```
<T extends X> void g(T);     //G1
<T extends A & B> void g(T); //G2

g(x); // calls G1
```

We can call `G1`, but there is no way to call `G2` without redirection.
We cannot downcast to `A & B`, only to either `A` or `B`.

The `A & B` does not seem well intgrated into the type system (most people won't even know of it), therefore Java does not see `A` as being a different type from `A & B` when choosing which version of a method to dispatch to.

---

Futher examples of madness:

```
interface A
interface B extends A

<T extends A & B> void f(T)
<T extends B> void f(T)
```

This will compile, but you can't call either of them

```
B b = new B(){...}
f(B); // method reference is ambiguious.
```