# Making a custom dialog type safe - how to use type parameters for types that are not instanceof a class

Tags: java, generics, type-safety

I want to make the following code more type safe, but don't get type parameters in the right position.

I have an `abstract class Function implements FunctionInterface` with some functionality and displaying stuff implemented via the `FunctionInterface`. There's another generic `ReturnSomethingInterface<T>`. Now there are many functions that `extends Function` and a method

```
public Object openDialog(FunctionInterface myFunction)
{
  "display and do something with myFunction"
  Object returnValue = null;
  if (myFunction instanceof ReturnSomethingInterface<?>)
  {
    returnValue = myFunction.returnSomething();
  }
  return returnValue;
}
```

So obviously some functions will return something and others won't (`return null`) and the return type varies.

Solution so far:
- simply call `openDialog(myFunctionWithoutReturnValue)` and ignore the returned `null` value, or I have something like `MyReturnType result = (MyReturnType) openDialog(myFunctionWithReturnValueOfMyReturnType)`.

Here I will get warnings because there's the unchecked conversion from `Object` to `MyReturnType`.

My intended solution: using type parameters to bind the returned type to the generic type in the `ReturnSomethingInterface<T>`.

When I do something like `public <T, S extends FunctionInterface & ReturnSomethingInterface<T>> T openDialog(S myFunction)` I can now write `MyReturnType result = openDialog(myFunctionWithReturnValueOfMyReturnType)` without having to cast the returned value and without warning about an unchecked conversion.

My problem: functions that don't implement the `ReturnSomethingInterface` are no valid parameters for `openDialog()` any more.

What I would need or like to have is another method `openDialog(.. myFunction)` that accepts parameters that implement `FunctionInterface`, but do not implement `ReturnSomethingInterface`.

My question: is there something like that? Or is there a reason why there isn't something like that?

Workaround would be to rename `openDialog()` to `openDialogWithoutReturn()` for calls with parameters that won't return anything, but I'd prefer a solution with type parameters. Any ideas?

Comment: "Now there are many functions that extends Function and a method" what?

Comment: Is this related - ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392586/java-generic-method-constraints-exclude-type-from-constraint-to-prevent-erasur

Comment: @AshishMathew yes, I think it's quite similar - though I sill don't understand why eclipse can't do this stuff at compile time - guess, I have to go with a renamed second method, thanks for the link